# Handling multiple Lists in lambda forEach()

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-stream

Any way to do this with lambdas/streams?

```
public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
    List<CartItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < names.size(); ctr++) {
        items.add(new CartItem(names.get(ctr), prices.get(ctr), quantities.get(ctr), subTotals.get(ctr)));
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Check out this quick tutorial which uses short and simple examples https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams. Point 4 talks about mapping. It might be hard to remember all this initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IntStream`:

```
public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
    return IntStream.range(0,names.size())
                    .mapToObj(ctr -> new CartItem(names.get(ctr), prices.get(ctr), quantities.get(ctr), subTotals.get(ctr)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```